# C# async technique for writing to log file but first wait for previous log I/O to finish

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a need to write to a log file on occasion, sometimes a small flurry of rapid log requests, but don't want to wait for the I/O. However, what I DO want to wait for is for the I/O to complete (as in, stream closed) before the NEXT log entry is written. So if the first log I/O request is busy, further I/O requests will politely wait in line for their turn and not stomp all over each other.

I've cobbled together an idea, is there any reason why this won't work?
Using Framework 4.7.2 and 4.8, asp.net MVC web app.

I've defined a static Task t elsewhere so it's global to the app.

```
public static void ErrorLog(string file, string error)
{
    if (t != null)
        t.Wait();
    //using file system async - doesn't use thread pool
    var f = new FileStream(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "logs", file), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
    var sWriter = new StreamWriter(f);
    t = sWriter.WriteLineAsync($"### {error}").ContinueWith(c => sWriter.Close());
}
```

This seems to be working, with a simple stress test like:

```
ErrorLog("test.txt", string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(i++, 1000)));
```

Repeated a bunch of times. Variable i is just so I can see each write in order in the log.

The beauty is that I don't need to rewrite all my requests to be async and convert ErrorLog into a true async function. Which yeah would be ideal but it's too much code to modify today.

My concern is the last write, though it does seem to complete before the AppDomain is torn down when the web request completes, I don't think that's any kind of guarantee... I wonder if I need to do a t.Wait() at the end of each incoming web request that may write to the log... just to make sure the last log entry is complete before ending the request...

Comment: Mmm... why do u care if the I/O completed. Why don't build a queue with the messages and run a BackgroundService that will log your info? So the requests can end without worrying that the info will not be written into the logs.

Comment: Agreed, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks for an example of a background queuing service. Side note: `FileStream` needs a `using`, as does `StreamWriter`

Comment: This is not a .net Core app. Note that I said framework 4.7.2 and 4.8. @Charlieface if I add using then long messages don't complete - they get truncated in the log. If the async code is busy writing and the code falls out of the using scope, it looks like the file is forcibly closed even if the write isn't complete. I can live with a few garbage collected handles as I'm not logging extensively at all.

Comment: Please note that I'm not asking how to log, or the best way to log, I asked if there is any reason why that code WON'T work or is bad for some reason I'm overlooking. Like my tenuous grasp of async :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not awaiting the `Task` result of the write, which means that the AppDomain can be torn down in the middle.

Ideally if you were just going to wait on the write, you would do this:

```cs
public static async Task ErrorLog(string file, string error)
{
    //using file system async - doesn't use thread pool
    using (var f = new FileStream(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "logs", file), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    using (var sWriter = new StreamWriter(f))
    {
        await sWriter.WriteLineAsync($"### {error}"):
    }
}
```

---

However, this does not allow you to hand off the log writing without waiting. Instead you need to implement a `BackgroundService` and a queue of logs to write.

A *very* rough-and-ready implementation would be something like this:

```cs
public class LoggingService : BackgroundService
{
    private Channel<(string file, string error)> _channel = new Channel.CreateUnbounded<(string, string)>();

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                var (file, error) = await _channel.Reader.ReadAsync(token);
                await WriteLog(file, error, token);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task WriteLog(string file, string error, CancellationToken token)
    {
        using (var f = new FileStream(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "logs", file), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        using (var sWriter = new StreamWriter(f))
        {
            await sWriter.WriteLineAsync($"### {error}".AsMemory(), token):
        }
    }

    public async Task QueueErrorLog(string file, string error)
    {
        await _channel.Writer.WriteAsync((file, error));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of Channels so that was interesting. I agree the optimal solution is a queue like your example. For a quick hack I'm just putting a t.Wait() at the end of any request that does an ErrorLog() where t is my global Task (ugh, yeah globals, bad programmer) and it seems to be working fine. I need to carve out some time to do a proper queue and not depend on globals and remembering to add the t.Wait() like that. But I like how simple this hack is as a temp fix for now.